# Built-in Terrain analogs search: is it worth to use imported 3d-model?

Tags: unity, textures, models, terrain, tools

I think 3d-model is better than the built-in terrain-component in Unity when it comes to **optimization**. But when it comes to texturing terrain made in 3rd party 3d-modeller, how to apply resulting texture in Unity? If the terrain is too big you can't bake it in UV map. Otherway you should split it in many UV's and each one is separate material, which kills performance in the game. Other decision that i see is to use generated type of material and just tile it across the terrain-mesh, but you can't draw the details like roads on it...

So i'm confused is it really worth it to use Unity's terrain analogs or there is no way to do so efficiently?

Comment: Can I summarize your question then as: "What should I use instead of Unity's built-in terrain?" If that's accurate, can you please edit your question to detail exactly what problems with Unity's terrain you're trying to solve, and what specific features or appearance an alternative solution needs to satisfy? Keep in mind that there's rarely one distinct "right way for performance" - performance is always balancing trade-offs between memory, processing, complexity, look, etc, so be precise about what you need.

Comment: You might also find this existing question interesting, [asking about how to achieve splat mapping similar to Unity's built-in terrains on a custom mesh](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/162618/unity-custom-multiple-texture-shader).

Comment: Thanks for the link, this question is generally very similiar to mine. In my question I suggested one the solutions to this and decided that it's performance sensitive too because of the many materials used.
So i'm seeking for the answer is it worth it and do you have any other solutions\techniques to do this.